# How do I send a signal from my computer to my USB antenna

Tags: signal, antenna, computers, remote-control

I'm trying to make an RC car that can be controlled by my computer.

The heart of the car is a simple mother board from an old toy. It basically accepts a signal 49MHz from a controller with a 9V battery.

I want more range on the controller but the output strength isn't strong enough. The controller circuit is only rated for 9V, so I guess ramping up the power isn't an option.

Overall I want to output a 49MHz signal from my computer out of a USB port.

Is that possible? If not, any solution would be awesome.

Comment: The search term you need is "software defined radio", although it's quite a difficult field, and getting a suitable transmitter can be expensive.

Comment: yeah I'm brand new to the topic of radio transmissions and how to use them

Comment: *output a 49Mhz signal from my computer out of a usb port. IS THAT POSSIBLE* Not directly, a 49 MHz transmitter circuit that is controlled via USB would have to be designed and build. **That is not easy**, even for an experienced electrical engineer. So my advice is to **forget** about doing this, it is not going to happen.

Comment: I have a transmitter with a 49MHZ range i just don't know another way of amplifying the signal

Comment: Are you trying to design [SDR (Software-defined Radio) Transceiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio)? That's not easy...

Comment: A "USB antenna" is not a thing that exists.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't output a 49MHz signal from a USB port. Your USB port can output USB signals and power, nothing else.

What *is* possible is any number of ways to convert between the signals. One common hobbyist way is to plug an Arduino into the USB port, and use the Arduino to output digital signals that control a radio transmitter which you built.

In fact since you have the controller, you can probably figure out a way to amplify the signal from the controller, or modify the controller to make the power output higher.

Beware that depending on where you live, it's illegal to transmit more than a certain amount of power without a license.

Comment: (as far as I'm aware, you won't go to jail or anything; if anyone notices interference on their own toys caused by your circuit, you'll get a warning and maybe a small fine)